# Match Multiple Lines in Sed and Delete One of Those Matched Lines (RegExp Happens Multiple Times in File)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

ok so i have this file for an example it looks like this as text file test.test input into sed

```
Input:
3.00
123.00
sdfasdfs
123.12
3.00
asdfasdf
3.00,123.00
asdfasdf
```

I would like to get this kind of output

```
Desired Output:
123.00
sdfasdfs
3.00
asdfasdf
3.00,123.00
asdfasdf
```

i have been trying this with no success

```
cat test.test | 
sed 'N;/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]/s/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n//g'
```

it fails in that sed only does the substitution once... it give me this output instead of the expected output

```
Erroneous Output From the Above Command:
123.00
sdfasdfs
123.12
3.00
asdfasdf
3.00,123.00
asdfasdf
```

someone please help me understand where i am going wrong in sed

edit:

the point of this is to find double lines that have something of the form [0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] and remove the first one... it says it in the title i need to match two lines of the form [0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] and delete the first line in the matched expression leaving only one [0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] expression, I have tried the above mentioned sed command and it only affects one match and not all in the file.  Those numbers that are there are just representative and could be anything from the pattern [0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] the order must stay the same and the file is actually quite bigger and there are many files that i am running this on, and the root problem is that it does this substitution once and then leaves the file, i need to it to run it for all instances

edit2:
I have seen where my error is in the sed command... it is starting the pattern every other line, which is why it skips over the second match and matches the first
it seems this is a possible course of action to remedy the situation

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;N;/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]/s/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n//; ta'
```

but i feel that somehow this will not work on all occurrences in all files

is there any way to attach the marker not to the beginning of the expression, but to the end of the substitution? sed isnt that confusing, i just dont know how to do what is in my head.

Comment: why the down vote? no comment?

Comment: I Did not downvote, but why don't you even attempt to explain the goal so that we don't have to reverse engineer your question?

Comment: Pass the file through `sort | uniq` if the order is not important.

Comment: still missing the wanted process in human understanding term certainly with a failing sed sample that works but not like you want

Comment: i put the desired out put and put the input, and also put what i used to try and get the desired out put, i figured it would be obvious... sorry i will edit the question

Comment: also sorry i only put the extra value in the last instance to show that there were extra things after that initial value in some lines, and then i failed to put it in the erroneous output example it has been fixed... also the order is of strict importance and the file needs to be left in the order that it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]/s/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n//;P;D' file
```

This will progress through the file considering each pair of lines.

The `P` command prints the first line of the pattern space and appends a newline.

The `D` command deletes the first line of the pattern space and its newline. If then the pattern space is empty the default behaviour is invoked and the next line is read into the pattern space. If the pattern space is not empty it leaves it alone and does not read in the next line and then begins the first sed command.

Perhaps what you really want is this:

```
sed 'N;/[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]\n[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]/!P;D' file
```

Which does not print the first line if a pattern of a pair of lines matches.

Comment: i will give this a go, but to be honest for a more secure data set there are things that could follow the second [0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9] so i dont necessarily want to delete the whole line... but i think the first one will work and if i am correct it technically just looks at all two lines possible not every two lines as a set... sed is really finicky, and ill get back to you...  also thanks for not being pompous and helping me out

Comment: i would up vote but it doesnt let me this absolutely works perfectly, should i add this... i have now learned something new... how to pretty much put the marker in the middle, and i appreciate this (the learning)